# android.database and android.graphics for trend analysis

Tags: java, android, sqlite, graph

Is it possible to use android.database and android.graphics provided by the Android APIs to perform trend analysis (such as line graphs and pie charts)? I was thinking about reading the data points from the SQLite database and use those to act as coordinates for graphing points and etc by Java.

If this sounds feasible, then would this approach need a ContentProvider to be created?

This is for an android app that is not integrated with a server, the logic and database are in the client.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds feasible to me.  I haven't used an sqlite database before so I don't have any advice for you there.  However, I can recommend using [afreechart](http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/) to make nice charts for you application; it is easy to learn and use.